# Adding new fields to Magento 1.7 registration form

Tags: forms, magento, registration

Would anyone give me a step by step guide on how to ***add custom fields*** to Magento ***registration form*** which works on ***Magento 1.7***. I have come across plenty & all of them were either supported for older version or too complicated for my understanding as I am pretty much new to it.

Comment: It would be easier if you tell us what exactly you have already done and at which point you stuck trying the "too complicated" tutorials.

Comment: Well I guess I was pretty clear that I am a newbie and I am going nowhere through those tutorials & hence asking for a ***step by step guide***,if I was stuck anywhere I would have been asking the next step,isn't it?So is there a way anyone can help me on this?

Comment: This question may be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 3):

You need to add Customer Attribute

so you can do this with custom module you build or there is some modules out there that gives you this functionality  like [customer-attributes](http://amasty.com/customer-attributes.html)

It could be on the backend only or the frontend as well etc.. it has alot of features

This feature already in Enterprise edition but for community edition you need to implement it, or use custom modules

Comment: There is couple of alternatives also in github free or paid module,
https://github.com/dbashyal/Magento-Customer-Attributes
 and
https://github.com/iamniels/Magento-custom-address-attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain what you need without spending any euro... using this [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-attributes-4340.html) and then putting in your regiter.phtml and edit.phtml something like this:

```
            <li class="control">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="attribute-name" title="<?php echo $this->__('your pretty label') ?>" id="attribute-name" value="<?= $this->getCustomer()->getAttributeName()); ?>" class="input" />
                </div>
                <label for="attribute-name"><?php echo $this->__("your pretty label") ?></label>
            </li>
```